# Non-virus originated cases of System Volume Information folder existance on removable media

Tags: windows, malware

When an AV found a virus on my external drive in the System Volume Information folder, I could not understand why this folder appeared there in the first place. From the logic behind System Restore there should be no cases when the system creates restore points on the removable media (except maybe manual installation of a program file there). Or I miss something and there are chances this folder would appear on any removable media one day?

Comment: Remember that System Volume Information contains more than just the data for System Restore. The search index for that volume also is there for example (though I don't think you can index removable media). The folder even predates the System Restore feature :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System Restore may also monitor the external drive. This is of course a bad idea.

A possible workaround is to assign a permanent drive letter (the higher in the alphabet the better) to the external drive via Disk Management. To access Disk Management, go to Start - Run and type diskmgmt.msc then press enter.

Right click a partition, logical drive, or volume, and then click Change Drive Letter and Paths.

Do one of the following:

1. To assign a drive letter, click Add, click the drive letter you want to use, and then click OK.
2. To modify a drive letter, click it, click Change, click the drive letter you want to use, and then click OK.

Now go to System properties and do:

[image]

[image]

To get rid of this protected directory from an external drive, say G:, start cmd.exe using "Run as administrator" and enter the following:

```
G:
cd \
takeown /r /f "System Volume Information"
```

Answer y for yes when asked whether to replace the permissions.

After this you can now delete the directory.

Comment: (1) removable media don't have a recycle bin, (2) the recycle bin resides in `\$Recycle.Bin`. How would you delete (or restore) files from the recycle bin if it were in a location where even the administrator doesn't have access?

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: Sorry. I've reset my brain and my answer to the correct gear.

Comment: The problem is that I use this drives being mounted by TrueCrypt and the letters are always different, not because of the software, but because of human factor, when several disks are mounted, the order of mounting sometimes define the order of letter usage. Thanks anyway, now I see that system restore works with removable media

Comment: Just a question: why don't you specify the drive letter on the TrueCrypt mount command (/l) ?